# Intuition for $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=\infty$ but $\mathbb{P}(\tau = \infty)=0$

Tags: logic, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

In general, it is not uncommon in probability theory to encounter the result $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=\infty$ but $\mathbb{P}(\tau = \infty)=0$ for some stopping time $\tau$.

A specific example could be the answers to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928842/is-this-stopping-time-finite-a-s-bounded), which show that the stopping time $\tau$, defined as follows:

$$\tau = \inf \{ t \ge 0: B_{t} \ge W_{t} + e^{-t} \}$$

is unbounded (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ doesn't converge) but is almost surely finite.

($B_t$ and $W_t$ are two uncorrelated Standard Brownian Motions)

**In general, whenever we have $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=\infty$ but $\mathbb{P}(\tau = \infty)=0$ for some stopping time $\tau$, how do we interpret such a result in plain English?**

If I had to explain what this result means to a 1st year undergrad, or even someone starting a graduate course in probability, how could I explain this intuitively? Would there be any real-world practical examples where such result would hold?

I.e. "how can something take on average infinite amount of time, but with certainty, it takes less than an infinite time".

Comment: You could start by considering a single random variable $X$ with the property that $P[X<\infty]=1$ but $E[X]=\infty$. Such variables exist. Just give $X\geq 1$ a PDF that decays like $1/x^2$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: An expectation is, at heart, nothing more than a discrete sum or fancy integral, both of which can diverge to infinity without having any particular term being infinite. Empirically, if you were to track the mean of your process over time, it would always be growing.

Comment: How can an integral of a finite function be infinite? It's the same thing.